# In a RESTful API, what is the appropriate use of slash-separated and query string parameters?

Tags: rest

For example, which of these (if any) is most RESTful? Why??

```
/employees/id/45
/employees/?id=45
/employees/45
```

Thanks!

Comment: Remember that according to the REST principle [Hypermedia as the Engine of Application State](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS), clients should (other than the initial entry point) be following links your server provides, not constructing URLs of their own (except as expressed through form-like systems). The specific syntax of each URL is therefore an implementation detail of your server, not something that makes your API more or less RESTful, except insofar as it makes it easier or harder to design URLs for related resources which REST implies should exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'll almost always be GETting employees based on an ID, I'd just use

```
/employees/45
```

Are you planning on supporting employee lookup based on multiple properties? If so, go with:

```
/employees/id/45
```

Since you can then add

```
/employees/dob/19940604
```

---

Really, I think you'd want to have:

```
/employee/45
```

Which always returns a single instance of an employee (note that employee is singular),
and then some URL which returns an EmployeeCollection, based on criteria:

```
/employees/dob/19940604
/employees/lastname/crumbling
```

Comment: Cool, good suggestions. Is it possibly better to use a query string if you'd like to be able to combine filters on the collection? 

/employees/?dob=19940604&lastname=crumbling

Comment: Absolutely. Otherwise you'd be stuck with every possible combination of ... /employees/lastname/crumbling?dob=19940604 ... /employees/dob/20110604?lastname=crumbling, and so on...

Answer (score 1):

For a REST API item type employees is directly addressed. It is implied that the entity is uniquely identified with id. hence, most appropriate URL is

`/employees/45`

Though the other option
`/employees/?id=45`
is equally valid.

The main aspect is that GET/PUT/POST should be used appropriately against the same URL for respective API.

Comment: Great, thanks! Is it an issue that if you do something like /employees/posts/?id=45 it's ambiguous whether the id refers to post or employees?

(as opposed to /employees/45/posts/)

Comment: Yes. If you use /employees/posts/?id=45 than a usual interpretation is that you are referring to post number 45. /employees/45/posts/ is a better representation.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to your question, which one (if any) is most RESTful, is that **they are all equally RESTful.** This is because URIs are opaque to a REST client as a consequence of HATEOAS, though [they should be 'hackable'](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/rest-discuss/message/3232) to a human reader. When you click a link in a web browser, the URI is (or at least ought to be) hidden behind some more meaningful (semantic) text, such as earlier in this paragraph. It does not matter to you as a urse of the site what the address in the address bar is, unless you want to start exploring by chopping bits off the URI or adding/replacing your own terms.

If your question was intended to cover more the URI design or API design aspect than what is/is not RESTful, then please expand the question to discuss your API more.